# Flutter force to release foreground

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

How to release foreground to the previous application in Flutter (Dart) ? I mean, how to force to call the `onPause` or `viewWillDisappear` to let my app disappear and let the previous app come back to the foreground.

Is there a method thant I can call ?

*Edit :* I don't wan't to close my app, juste "minimize" it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter programmatically closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-programmatically-closing-the-app)

Comment: I don't want to close my app. I juste want to "minimize" it. I mean, let the previous app to come back in the foreground without closing mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a solution ! I haven't found yet a solution for the IOS side : I'm working on it.

I used `MethodChannel` to ask to the native side to minimize itself. For Android use **`this.moveTaskToBack(true);`** ! If you got an Objectif-C alternative, it will be perfect !

Dart:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 static const MethodChannel actionChannel = MethodChannel('method.channel');

  Future<void> _minimize() async{
   try{
     await actionChannel.invokeMethod('minimize');
   } on PlatformException catch(e) {
     print('${e.message}');
   }
 }
}
```

Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

 private static final String ACTION_CHANNEL = "method.channel";

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Action-post-alert method
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), ACTION_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("minimize")) {
                        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
                        result.success(true);
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: what about `ios`?

Answer (score 2):

You are struggling with a mismatch between Flutter's architecture and Android's. In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054527/launch-screen-from-native-background-service) you needed a way to bring your flutter app to the foreground, to which the answer is a full-screen intent notification. The problem is that in native Android, you would probably have used the `NEW_TASK` flag to start a new task. As Flutter only has one activity, it's necessary to use `USE_CURRENT` instead.

With `NEW_TASK`, you would use `Activity.finish()` to close it, closing just the new activity. If you did that with Flutter, that would probably close the whole app (because of the use of `USE_CURRENT`).

It might be possible to have a native Android app (allowing you to have more direct control of the launch of activities) and to use [Add2App](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps) to add the Flutter screen(s). If you get that to work, I'd like to know.

Comment: Thank you again for your precise answer. But as it said in GitHub : Add2App "_APIs and tooling are not stable_" and it make me uncomfortable to take a way in a not reliable technology.


Is there another cross-platform solution with flutter to properly "minimize" my app without closing it ? I want to avoid as much as possible to duplicate methods in both plateforms.


I know even less about IOS than on Android. But it seems that there is an event of releasing foreground in both plateforms. I'm pretty sur that we can force it.


**Your help is really appreciate Richard**

Comment: You should read the whole section on activities particularly the bit on [tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack). To pop your activity you need to call finish, but if that's your *only* activity then you exit - that's the fundamental conflict between Flutter and `NEW_TASK`. I believe that the solution will lie somewhere in the Add2App area, but I haven't found it yet. (I need it too ;-) ) Check out other frameworks like React Native which may behave differently and be better for your use case.