# Flutter, how to launch specific screen from FCM background message

Tags: android, flutter

I need to launch a specific screen in flutter when I get notification from  FCM while app killed/background from native I see this link
[Launch screen from native background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054527/launch-screen-from-native-background-service) but I can't achieve it, any help please.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and I fixed it by adding `"click_action": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'` to my data payload in my cloud function. Then in my android/app AndroidManifest.xml, inside the `<activity>` tag I added:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: no i mean automatically open the app not on click the notification when the app in background or killed like whatsapp call

Comment: see whatsapp call how open the call screen without any user action